# Does C# recognize numbers beginning with digits outside 0-9?

Tags: c#, unicode

In C#, a lexical token is recognized as an identifier or keyword if it begins with a letter or underscore, and a number if it begins with a digit.

A letter in this context is not restricted to `[A-Za-z]`; it can be any Unicode letter, as recognized by `char.IsLetter`.

Are any characters outside `[0-9]` similarly recognized as digits for the purpose of recognizing numeric literals?

Comment: Are you looking for something like a hex literal, e,g, `0x12ab`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere arabic numbers for example (٠, ١, ٢, ٣ etc) are both recognized as Digit, and Number

Comment: @HimBrobBeere `'\u0E51'` (Thai number one) for example

Comment: You have to crate your own class.  If you have a hex number it will use a-f for digits.  You could create base (any base) arithmetic class where the digits can be unicode characters.

Comment: No.  Hard to guess at the motivation behind this question, but Roslyn lets you change the rules as you see fit.  Change [this code](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/b3480b9ab9fb823a4a5b622fdfe1464bf62ecec6/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Parser/Lexer.cs#L859).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, but it is more complex than just that.

If you look at [the language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#integer-literals), you will see what I mean:

```
integer_literal
    : decimal_integer_literal
    | hexadecimal_integer_literal
    ;

decimal_integer_literal
    : decimal_digit+ integer_type_suffix?
    ;

decimal_digit
    : '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9'
    ;

integer_type_suffix
    : 'U' | 'u' | 'L' | 'l' | 'UL' | 'Ul' | 'uL' | 'ul' | 'LU' | 'Lu' | 'lU' | 'lu'
    ;

hexadecimal_integer_literal
    : '0x' hex_digit+ integer_type_suffix?
    | '0X' hex_digit+ integer_type_suffix?
    ;

hex_digit
    : '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9'
    | 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D' | 'E' | 'F' | 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f';
```

As you can see, the `+` or `-` are not part of the integer literal specification, so for the start of this rule, it always requires a digit (either `0-9` for decimal integers, and `0`, followed by `x` for hexadecimal integers).

The rule parsing is more complex than just checking for the first character to determine which rule to follow. Reading up on ANTLRs look ahead methodology ([LL(*)](https://www.antlr.org/papers/LL-star-PLDI11.pdf)) will learn you a lot. Simply said, the entire rule must parse, or it will fail to parse that rule. It isn't just solely based on the start of the rule.

Comment: "No"? Really? Then why does `Char.IsDigit('၉')` return `true`?

Comment: The question is about the parser/lexer, `char.IsDigit` is totally irrelevant to it. @Rafalon

Comment: Then why does OP talk about `char.IsLetter`?

Comment: Because OP thinks they are somewhat related, as if the parser is written in C# or so. @Rafalon

Comment: @Rafalon The first sentence is clearly about the parser, not the language implementation itself.

Comment: That's right, then I misinterpreted the question, my bad

Comment: Yeah, assumptions... No problem. @Rafalon